# If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do facebook manages session for its api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am developing a REST api using PHP (Laravel framework). While i was playing with the `facebook's GRAPH API EXPLORER` what i noticed is that it uses session like mechanism.

[image: Logged in Image]

When i am logged out and try the explorer by providing my access token i get the following error.

[image: Logged out Image]

now what my point is that facebook is using the session here beside just access token. My question is how come one can able to use session in `REST Api` because when i request my api using `CURL` the server generates new session for every request.

Is there any hack if yes then how it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now what my point is that facebook is using the session here beside just access token

Actually, the graph api explorer will automatically append access_token=blah_blah if you omit it, so its sessions are actually only based on access_token. Your access_token must have been expired. Debug it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: and thats exactly what i am asking how does facebook knows that the user associated with the access token logged out? in the above example i posted i manually logged out. lets say what if i just close the browser how facebook will ever know that i am logged out? please help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. When you manually log out, the client-side Facebook code will reset your session and *not* send an access_token. If you just close your browser, you aren't logged out, your session is still stored in fb cookies and will resume the next time around.

Comment: OK - got it. You used the access_token from when you were logged in, and it didn't work any more. That is because when you log out, Facebook invalidates that token. To prevent that from happening in your application, you have to exchange the short-lived access token that you are given with a long(er)-lived one. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/